# Cakephp 3.6: get data from form - Strange workaround

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, get, request

I want to implement a search form so this is what I have done so far:

`index.ctp`:

```
    <?php
    $base_url = array('controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'index');
    echo $this->Form->create('Filter',array('url' => $base_url, 'class' => 'filter'));
    // Add a basic search 
    echo $this->Form->input('search', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => "Name or surname..."));

    echo $this->Form->submit("Search");

    echo $this->Form->end();
    ?>
```

`CustomersController.php`

```
public function index()
    {

        $conditions = array();

        debug($this->request->getData()); //form field is not passed
        debug($this->request->getData('search')); //form field is not passed
        $conditions['OR'] = array(
            array('Customers.name LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->getData('search') . '%'),
            array('Customers.surname LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->getData('search') . '%')
        );

        $this->Customers->recursive = 0;
        $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 8,
            'conditions' => $conditions
        );
        $this->set('customers', $this->paginate()); 

    }
```

But search field value is not passed to the `controller`. What is going wrong?

**EDIT**

There is something wrong with the `CustomersController.php` code, because if change the `$base_url` in `index.ctp` to another controller then I can get the data correctly

**BUT THIS WORKS**

`index.ctp`

```
<div class="Search">
        <?php
        // The base url is the url where we'll pass the filter parameters
        $base_url = array('controller' => 'ExpiringServices', 'action' => 'index');
        echo $this->Form->create('Filter',array('url' => $base_url, 'class' => 'filter'));
        // Add a basic search 
        echo $this->Form->control('search', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => "Name or surname..."));

        echo $this->Form->submit("Search");

        echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>
    </div>
```

`ExpiringServicesController.php`

```
public function index()
{

    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');


    debug($this->request->getData('search'));
    //.....
}
```

**NEW EDIT (WORKAROUND)**

Strangely if I change:

```
$base_url = array('controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'index');
```

To

```
$base_url = array('controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'index',123);
```

It works! but why???

Comment: What does `debug($this->request->getData());` give you as output?

Comment: I tried your code, literally just copied index.ctp , and displayed debug($this->request->getData());

I'm getting the search data.

Comment: @BryanLoresto I dont know what is going wrong though... it doesnt work here.

Comment: @GregSchmidt it gives empty array: "[ ]"

Comment: @BryanLoresto is it possible that something else is blocking the data passed to controller?

Comment: @netdev I haven't experienced something like that, are using Security Component? or maybe something that's validating the form ?

Comment: @BryanLoresto nope... and the problem is that I use the exact same code in another page and it works :(

Comment: @BryanLoresto please check updated post ... it works but in a very weird way

Comment: I wonder if it's redirecting to the index page somehow, thereby losing your posted data. If you watch your network requests with browser dev tools, do you see just the post to the index page, or is it followed by a get?